# Unable to query Solr datatset where field results contain an array with curly braces

Tags: solr

I am trying to search a term in Solr index where the results contain curly brackets like below:

```
[
  { 
    "courseid":10479,
    "title":[{"en" = "Formation aux tests de collaboration par semaine - Stefano"},{"fr" = 
    "Formation aux tests de collaboration par semaine - Stefano"}],
    "shortname":[{"en" = "Formation aux tests de collaboration par semaine - Stefano"}, 
           {"fr" = "Formation aux tests de collaboration par semaine - Stefano"}]
   }
]
```

I have tried searching using query like `q=title:Formation` or  `q=title:collabration` but this does not provide any result however I can easily search with other attributes like courseid `q=courseid:10479`

I have tried searching the blogs but I cant find a clear answer

Comment: What is the type of the `title` field? The response seems a bit weirdly formatted as well, since it should be `"{\"en\" = ...` if it were a proper list entry in a JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to understand that how exactly are you indexing the data. title field seems to be an array of json but **"="**(equals) operator is used instead of **":"**(colon) Assuming that you have indexed it as array of json, you can try perform searching like this

> title.en: Formation or title.fr: Formation